# jsfiddle framework and extensions not showing

Tags: javascript, frameworks, jsfiddle

I signed up for jsfiddle so that I could better learn javascript, html, and css. I'm following a tutorial on jsfiddle and jquery on Youtube. The problem I have is that I can't access the framework and extension options. Inside jsfiddle documentation I don't see any forum or contact that I can access to address this problem. So I come to stackoverflow for help. I'm going to show you an image of the jsfiddle page that I'm following and then an image of my jsfiddle page so you can see the difference.
[image] 
Now here is an image of my jsfiddle page. As you can see my page doesn't show the frameworks or extension options. 
[image: jsfiddle with frameworks and extension options]

Is there something that I can do to open the frameworks and extension options.

Comment: Click the gear icon next to JAVASCRIPT.

Comment: Yeah click the gear icon in JavaScript area...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new jsfiddle website version, you have to click on the "JavaScript" settings button, top right corner of the JavaScript section, in order to access the "Framework and extensions" panel.

[image]

Comment: I opened a new account in jsfiddle hoping that I would see something that I missed but I didn't see anything. I'm going to go back signout and then signin. I tried the setting but that didn't yield  any frameworks options. For some reason I don't see Javascript. In the upper right corner I see settings but those settings don't take me to Javascript. I'll keep looking.

Comment: @swydell _"For some reason I don't see Javascript"_ "JAVASCRIPT" appears in image at Question http://i.stack.imgur.com/hp78s.png  at right of `var color="blue";`

Comment: I think I got it. I found a forum in Github. The javascript you spoke of is inside the javascript pane. I went there and saw the other frameworks. Thanks a million. Now I can proceed with my training.